# Adding data to User profile

Tags: custom-field, users

Some plugins for wordpress add fields to the users profile. For example "Company" or "Store" or "Group". How can I add the values to this fields from a custom a frontend registration form, with custom fields, compatible with the users new profile fields.
Thank you

Comment: You could use [update_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/) or [add_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.